# Saber se usuário possui Waze instalado

Tags: android, route

Tenho uma aplicação que realiza rotas entre a posição atual e um determinado ponto.

Para isto, chamo uma Activity:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+ item.getLatitude() + "," + item.getLongitude()));
     startActivity(intent);
```

Agora vamos implementar uma funcionalidade onde o usuário poderá selecionar qual `App` ele gostaria de usar: *GoogleMaps* ou *Waze*.

Isto será feito através de um `Spinner`, e só vou exibir o Waze, se o mesmo estiver instalado no Smartphone do usuário.

Gostaria de saber como faço para descobrir se o usuário possui o Waze instalado, e como faço para abrir ele ao invés do GoogleMaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conforme esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18752247/1518921) (eu não sei se algo mudou nas novas APIs, conforme necessário irei ajustar o código), você pode fazer isto:

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, PackageManager packageManager) {
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, 0);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Creio que o nome do pacote do waze seja `com.waze`, use assim:

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

if (isPackageInstalled("com.waze", pm)) {
    //código para waze
} else {
    //talvez um webView para googlemaps
}
```

---

Você também pode testar o protocolo usando `Intent`:

```
final String uriwaze = Uri.parse("waze://...");
final String urigooglemaps = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?...");

final Intent wazeNavitage = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriwaze);

try {
    startActivity(wazeNavitage); //Tenta abrir o Waze
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    final Intent googleMapsNavigate = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, urigooglemaps);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Não pude testar ainda, mas creio que seja este o caminho

Answer (score 1):

Você deve direcionar a sua URI direto pro Waze e caso o usuário não tenha irá listar os Apps apropriados

Exemplo:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("waze://?ll=" + item.getLatitude() + "," + item.getLongitude() + "&navigate=yes"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Então, mas caso ele não esteja instalado, não haverá a opção para ele